# Which fork of GitX is the most active?

Tags: macos, git, gui

I've been using the original GitX but I've noticed it hasn't had any updates for quite a while. Which version of GitX is the most active, in terms of updates/stability/features?

- [The original](https://github.com/pieter/gitx) ([Screenshots](http://gitx.frim.nl/seeit.html#screenshots) & [Info](http://gitx.frim.nl/index.html))
- [The brotherbard fork](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx) ([Screenshot](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx/wiki))
- [Germán Laullón's fork](https://github.com/laullon/gitx) ([Screenshots & Info](http://gitx.laullon.com/))
- Some other fork?

Answer (score 11):

Judging by [the](https://github.com/pieter/gitx/commits/master) [commit](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx/commits/experimental) [histories](https://github.com/laullon/gitx/commits/master), I'd say Laullón's fork.

**Update to this answer**, Judging by [the commit histories](https://github.com/rowanj/gitx/commits/master), I'd say [rowanj's fork](https://github.com/rowanj/gitx) now a days. Download [link](https://github.com/rowanj/gitx#download-the-latest-binary) is in the Readme.md with lots of changes!

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it wasn't nearly as stable as the brotherbard fork

Comment: Note that most stable is not always the same as most active. I have just started using Germán Laullón's fork, and it works pretty nicely for me… although I am running from the github build to fix the git-svn issue in 0.8.1.

Comment: GitX (L) is almost unusable for me, I don't know what he did to the codebase, but it's extremely slow, and with multiple projects open at once it becomes unbearable. The brotherboard fork comes with the same sidebar and is super fast, like the vanilla GitX.

Comment: Cf. [GitX: a short history](http://cczona.com/blog/2012/05/gitx-a-short-history/). Looks like the momentum is behind [GitX-dev](http://rowanj.github.com/gitx/) (neé `GitX-L(rowanj)`), which seems to have regained teh snappy that slothlike GitX-L lost.

Comment: In 2016 this tool is still invaluable to my workflow.